# Is the handler for the onSettingsChanged event still broken in the JavaScript API for Excel?

Tags: excel, events, office-js

Has the bug noted two years ago in the question "How to register handler for SettingsChanged event in Office Web Add-ins" ever been fixed?

If it has been fixed, what am I doing wrong in my add-in work?  Two button controls in my add-in create/change settings via statements like

```
    Office.context.document.settings.set(key, value);
```

and code for my task pane, which is always displayed, successfully reads these settings in statements like

```
    if (Office.context.document.settings.get(key) === value) { }
```

But I haven't found a way to trigger that code whenever a setting changes.  I've added an event handler with the following code, which executes successfully

```
    await Excel.run(async context => {
        context.workbook.settings.onSettingsChanged.add(this.handleSettingsChange);
        await context.sync();
    });
```

But handleSettingsChange is never executed.

If the bug has not been fixed, is there a workaround by which a click on a button control can trigger an update in the taskpane?

Answer (score 0):

onSettingsChanged
Occurs when the Settings in the document are changed.

The Settings.set method affects only the in-memory copy of the settings property bag. Settings.saveAsync() needs to be called to persist the settings in document then you will see the event is fired.

Comment: My code contains a call of Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync, but the event is not fired.

Comment: Will you share your code snippet? And you may can try the modern way to set settings, for example:
{
    const settings = context.workbook.settings;
    console.log("Create Settings");
    settings.add("SettingKey1", "S1");

    await context.sync();
}

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share your gist, I just have a try, the event can be triggerred, Here is a sample code gist you could have a try
https://gist.github.com/lumine2008/ad6ad32bbe4c40ce28067fbb1b4dde05

You could also try Office.context.document.settings 
https://gist.github.com/lumine2008/cde9956fc1f7feefbd8278c844f3bd9e